# Funk SVD for binary data - product like or dislike

Tags: clustering, recommender-system, matrix-decomposition

Assume the following situation:

you have a user-item sparse matrix. However, instead of the usual 1 to 5 rating scale, items can only receive a positive (1) or negative (-1) feedback.

Thus, the matrix looks like so:

```sql
  user_id |  item_1   |  item_2   |  item_3   |  ...
----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------
     1    |    -1     |     1     |     0     |  ...
----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------
     2    |     0     |     1     |     1     |  ...
----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-------
     3    |     1     |     0     |     0     |  ...
```

In said matrix, **1** represents a positive feedback, **-1** a negative one, and **0** means the user has never seen the product.

My ultimate goal is to achieve a meaningful representation of the users in order to cluster them.

By scouting around the web I have learned that a good approach to do so is applying matrix factorization on my original user-item matrix, and then run the clustering algorithm on the resulting user's matrix. One of the most famous methods to decompose the matrix is using [Funk SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_factorization_(recommender_systems)).

However, Funk SVD (and subsequent improvements) all seem to be built to work on a traditional item rating scale (1-5), and not on binary data; i.e. by [using squared error as its loss function](https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/matrix_factorization.html), as noted in the docs of the python [library](http://surpriselib.com/) I'm working with.

This approach doesn't seem the most ideal to me; given the situation I'm dealing with, using log-loss / cross-entropy as the loss function seems a more sane approach.

It's also true that I'm not exactly a genius when it comes to these subjects, so my ideas might be completely misled.

What approach would you suggest?

Comment: You seem to be concerned over whether the data is nominal vs ordinal. Why? Do you care about preserving either the permutation vs isotonic group actions?

Comment: I would make sure you understand that you should not have 0's but NA's (ie you don't want to add the zero items to your loss.

Comment: I agree,  with you that the matrix factorisation approach doesn't fit into a statistical max likelihood approach.  factorisation machines (rendle) do this and turn it into a standard classification problem. you might want to look at this paper too - http://stanford.edu/~rezab/nips2014workshop/submits/logmat.pdf where they do turn it into a classification problem. 
However, I am not sure that you can model your like/dislike data as binary. i would view it as ordinal: like /hate/indifferent.

Comment: @seanv507 as far as I know, Funk SVD ignores the missing items by default. Tbh, the library I'm using gets as input the long form dataframe instead of a wide one, so there's no 0s anyway to begin with.

Comment: @seanv507 side note, I took a quick glance at that paper, will look better tomorrow. I however noticed that the method explained requires non negative values in the user-item matrix, where they consider values > 0 to be number of user interactions, and 0s to be "user doesn't know about this". How could I fit my case here, where I have "user dislike this item"?

Comment: yes that's my point- its for doing logistic regression, whereas an ordinal regression would be more appropriate to your case.  Though I am having problems understanding whether or not your data has 4 values: (like, dislike, no opinion,NA- user didn't experience),  - where no opinion means seen but no strong views either way.  in this case an ordinal model makes sense (you have 3 user "responses"). If you are saying the user always has to respond either like or dislike, then a binary (logistic regression ) model makes sense.

Comment: @seanv507 it has 3 values. "Like", "Dislike", "Never seen the item". So yeah the second case you mentioned. Question is, in a binary model, how do you encode the "Never seen"? I was reading in this notebook (https://everdark.github.io/k9/notebooks/ml/matrix_factorization/matrix_factorization.nb.html#22_binary_matrix_factorization) that in the case of a logistic regression, the author encodes its values the same way as I did. It seems reasonable, although I'm still perplexed by how the "0s" would be treated.

Comment: That's what I was saying about 0 vs NA.  You do not "encode" "Never seen the item". I believe in the code ((everdark.github.io/k9/notebooks/ml/matrix_factorization/…) the developer uses the `self.mask` to ignore the elements with value zero, so they are just never used in any of the calculations. That's why I am saying its better to think of them as missing (NA).[ you could equally "encode" unknown with value -1923 .. it's (should be) irrelevant.

more practically assuming you have large numbers you would use sparse matrices (only storing location of non zero values)

Comment: @seanv507 yeah, after reading some papers, the 2006 netflix challenge and a bunch of code / pseudo-code of related stuff, I understood that it doesn't really matter at all as the missing values are not calculated anyway. It mostly depends on which library one is using, essentially.
Btw thanks for the headsup for that paper cause it really set me on the right track.